# C# Console app : Read a file from disk both when ran as standalone and when ran from ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis

I want to know how to be able to **read a text file** from both :

when running as a standalone

**and**

when running from a host ASP.NET app.

---

I am aware of the Server.MapPath command but it only works on the ASP.NET app and I want the file loading to be done from the console application.

---

Let's begin with an empty project and create two projects :

First, a Console application :

[image]

Then, a ASP.NET MVC application :

[image]

Once we have our two projects, let's create a text file :

[image]

And put something in there :

[image]

Make sure it is included in the bin folder :

[image]

Now, we can finally read the file content like this :

[image]

Using the following code :

[image]

We get the desired output.

Now, as stated in the beginning of this post, I want to be able to access the file from the same project, but called from the ASP.NET app.

Let's add the console app as a project dependency of TestWebApp :

[image]

And call it's method like so :

[image]

Now I get this error :

[image]

---

I want to know how I would go on and be able to load the file both when running the app by itself (console app) or when running from a host web service (asp.net web server).

Comment: I think you don't have to execute the console app like that. You can just divde them into two project and invoke the console application via Process.start. As long as IIS application pool identity have permission to access the console app, it should always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AppContext.BaseDirectory`. This is the directory for which the runtime checks to resolve assemblies. In your context, this is the closest to the output directory.

Now there is a difference between what it returns for the Console App vs Web App. The below common code would address both.

```
var appContextBase = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
var filePath = appContextBase.IndexOf("bin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1 ? "bin/Files/File.txt" : "Files/File.txt";
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(appContextBase + filePath);
Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
```

For Console App, `AppContext.BaseDirectory` returns something like this - `"C:\\Users\\user123\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\MySamples\\MySamples\\bin\\Debug\\"`

For Web App, it returns something like this - `"C:\\Users\\user123\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\MySamples\\MyWebApp\\"`

That is the reason I have added the ternary operator check on the `filePath`.

Comment: Please give it a try and mark it as answer if it works for you.